# Ajax. Одно из полей не отправляется

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день, гуру.

Подскажите где ошибка, в базу записывается  только одно поле - $_POST[img]. Где и в чем ошибка? Почему может не попадать в базу $_POST[link] и $_POST[text]?

html

```
             <script>
                $(function(){
                    $("button[name=mybutton]").on("click",function(){

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "php/load.php", // куда отправляем
                            cashe:false,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: ({
                                type:"addComplex",
                                text:$("input[name=text]").val(),
                                link:$("input[name=link]").val(),
                                img:$("input[name=img]").val()  }),     //что отправляем(в PHP получаем $_POST['num'])
                            // после получения ответа сервера
                            success: function(data){
                                json = $.parseJSON(data); //парсим json
                                $('#answer1').html(json.answer); //отправляем в div
                            } //конец success
                        });// конец $.ajax
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

php

```
if($_POST['type'] ==  "addComplex") { // пришли ли данные
    # Соединение
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

# Выбор базы данных
    mysql_select_db('link_db') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO complex ( link, img, text) VALUES ( '$_POST[link]', '$_POST[img]', '$_POST[text]')");

    $arr = array(); //результирующий массив

//Если запрос пройдет успешно то в переменную result вернется true
    if($result == 'true')
    {   $arr['answer'] = "Данные успешно отправлены";   }
    else {  $arr['answer'] = "Ошибка". mysql_error();    }
    echo json_encode($arr); //отправляем в поток
}
```

Список полей:

`link_db`.`complex` (
`id` ,
`link` ,
`img` ,
`text`
)

Comment: "addInstructions" или "addComplex" ?

Comment: пардон, исправил вопрос

Comment: В php-коде sql-инъекция сидит.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил, есть несколько подобных форм на странице. Имена $_POST[link] и $_POST[text] дублируются. Видимо был конфликт.

Comment: Поэтому надо получать инпуты по id, а не по имени. Имена у разных полей совпадать могут, а id обязаны быть уникальными.